# What should an "out" parameter be in case of failure?

Tags: c#, .net, null, software-design

I have read this related question: [What should the out value be set to with an unsuccessfull TryXX() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862207/what-should-the-out-value-be-set-to-with-an-unsuccessfull-tryxx-method)

However that question deals with primitive types such as integers etc.

I am implementing a similar `TryXXX`, the answers on that question say that the default value of `out` should be `null` when the method is unsuccessful. However the `out` type in my method is a non-nullable value type.

Take for example my code:

```
    public bool TryParseFileLine(string fileLine, out FileResult result)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileLine))
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
        // Logic here for if the string wasn't empty etc.
    }

    public struct FileResult
    {
        public bool IsValid;
        public string Value;
    }
```

The `result = null` line does not compile because `Cannot convert null to 'FileResult' because it is a non-nullable value type`.

So in my situation, what should the value of `result` be when the method fails? Ideally I would like it to be null because that is what makes the most sense to me.

Edit: Would using `Nullable<FileResult>` be a good idea here? For example:

```
        public bool TryParseFileLine(string fileLine, out Nullable<FileResult> result)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileLine))
        {
            result = null;
            return false;
        }
        // Logic here for if the string wasn't empty etc.
        result = new FileResult();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, either use `default(FileStruct)` (and make sure the value makes some sort of sense - it's the equivalent of `new FileStruct()` for value types), or better yet, **scratch the `out` parameter** altogether and return a nullable `FileStruct?` value.

```
public FileResult? TryParseFileLine(string fileLine)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileLine))
        return null;

    ...
}
```

The `bool TrySomething(out Result result)` pattern predates nullable structs in the langugage, and IMHO shouldn't be used for new code as it makes it inconventient for the caller (because of the need to declare an additional variable most of the time).
Using a nullable struct as a return value is much nicer to the caller, and doesn't require you to return meaningless values in your code.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more on this default? I've only used default with switches before. I was trying the out parameter to follow the same way that TryParse for example works.

I hadn't considered returning a nullable type instead. Is that generally the modern way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: @user9993 [`default(T)` (docs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx) is a construct primarily meant for generics, where it returns `null` for reference types and the *default* value for value types, which is what you get by calling the default constructor: `new T()`. I think nullable value types made the `TryParse` pattern largely obsolete, the existing functions date back to .NET 1.0. You should strive to avoid `out` whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

> what should the value of result be when the method fails?

You can simply use `default(FileStruct)`.

This will give you a `FileStruct` with default values. But you wouldn't care about it since you only do this when you return `false` and therefore the caller is not expected to use this value.